# I think I deleted bash!

Tags: bash, files, delete

I am attempting to make a PXE server that will boot Ubuntu (live cd) 14.04. I was trying to copy the **bash** file from

> /bin/bash

to

> /var/lib/tftpboot/Ubuntu/bin/bash

I must have used the "mv" command instead. Now, I can't log in via SSH (or even the local console)! **I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 under VirtualBox.** When I try to log in, I get this message:

> Cannot execute /bin/bash: No such file or directory

Then, I am immediately logged back out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Restart the Virtual Machine. At the Grub OS Selection menu (you may have to press press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make it show), edit the default entry by pressing <kbd>e</kbd>. Change the `linux` line and add `rw init=/bin/dash`. You'll boot into the `dash` shell. Copy back `bash`. Other options include `/bin/static-sh` (will start Busybox).

It's unlikely that you have an existing `init` parameter, but if you do have one, replace it. The `rw` option tells it to mount the root filesystem with write permissions (the default added by Grub is `ro`, IIRC, so if `ro` is there, delete that as well).

Once your work is done, continue boot using:

```
exec /sbin/init
```

Sources:

- [Why does Linux allow ‘init=/bin/bash’?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34462/70524)
- [Linux root password recovery](http://www.softpanorama.org/Commercial_linuxes/Startup_and_shutdown/root_password_recovery.shtml#n_shutting_down_after_init_bin_bash_linuxquestions_org)

Comment: Just add `init=/bin/dash`? Not replace an existed `init` or anything like that?

Comment: @Seth I didn't mention an existing `init` is those are rare (I have yet to see one in a normal Grub menu entry). Thanks for the reminder, I forgot to mention the `rw` parameter.

Comment: If you have a running SSH server and don't want to restart the VM, you could try invoking SSH with an alternate login shell explicitly e.g. something like `ssh -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx /bin/dash -li`

Comment: @steeldriver unlikely to work. That command will be passed to the user's login shell as a command, which will fail, since the login shell is bash.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GUI installed, try to login via GUI (via Display Manager). Your shell may fallback to `sh`, and use that to fix the problem.

Otherwise, try to attach the storage to another computer, and copy the bash back.

Comment: I have run into a bigger problem: /bin/bash is actually there, but it is still not working.

Comment: In an attempt to solve the problem myself, I must've reproduced the problem with **/sbin/init** this time! Now, whenever I boot the VM, I get a kernel panic. Oops...